# web logs parsing for Spark Streaming

Tags: parsing, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I plan to create a system where I can read web logs in real time, and use apache spark to process them. I am planning to use  kafka to pass the logs to spark streaming to aggregate statistics.I am not sure if I should do some data parsing (raw to json ...), and if yes, where is the appropriate place to do it (spark script, kafka, somewhere else...)  I will be grateful if someone can guide me. Its kind of a new stuff to me. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Kafka is a distributed pub-sub messaging system. It does not provide any way to parse or transform data it is not for that. But any Kafka consumer can process, parse or transform the data published to Kafka and republished the transformed data to another topic or store it in a database or file system.

There are many ways to consume data from Kafka one way is the one you suggested, real-time stream processors(apache flume, apache-spark, apache storm,...).

So the answer is no, Kafka does not provide any way to parse the raw data. You can transform/parse the raw data with [spark](http://spark.apache.org/) but as well you can write your own consumer as there are many [Kafka clients ports](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Clients) or use any other built consumer [Apache flume](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/11/flafka-apache-flume-meets-apache-kafka-for-event-processing/), [Apache storm](http://hortonworks.com/blog/storm-kafka-together-real-time-data-refinery/), etc